iOS Widget URL Handling Not Working on Real Device
iOS Widget URL Handling Not Working on Real Device
Problem
I've developed an iOS app with a widget for a clipboard manager. The widget works fine in the simulator, but on a real device, the URL handling to copy items from the widget isn't functioning as expected.
App Structure

Main app: Clipboard manager
Widget: Displays clipboard items
Intended functionality: Tapping an item in the widget should copy it to the clipboard

Current Implementation
URL Handling in AppDelegate:
func handleURL(_ url: URL) {
    guard url.scheme == "clipboardcompact",
          url.host == "copy",
          let itemId = UUID(uuidString: url.lastPathComponent) else {
        print("Invalid URL: \(url)")
        return
    }
    
    let context = persistenceController.container.viewContext
    let request: NSFetchRequest<Clipboard> = Clipboard.fetchRequest()
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", itemId as CVarArg)
    
    do {
        let items = try context.fetch(request)
        if let item = items.first, let content = item.content {
            UIPasteboard.general.string = content
            print("Copied to clipboard: \(content)")
        } else {
            print("Item not found or content is nil")
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error fetching item: \(error)")
    }
}

URL Registration in Info.plist:
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
  <dict>
    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <array>
      <string>clipboardcompact</string>
    </array>
  </dict>
</array>

What I've Tried

Verified URL scheme registration in Info.plist
Checked App Groups configuration
Ensured the widget extension has necessary permissions
Verified that the App Intent file is shared between the main app and widget targets

Questions

Why might URL handling work in the simulator but not on a real device?
Are there any common pitfalls or configuration issues I should look out for?
How can I debug URL handling on a real device more effectively?
Are there any alternatives to URL handling for widget-to-app communication in this scenario?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

